# Appending/translating CSV data to GeoPackage with drop drown attribute Fields

Tags: fields-attributes, csv, geopackage, append, translate

I will preface this with some context.  I've created a data collection Project that I use in QField, comprised of multiple Geopackage layers that have been heavily modified in the Attribute Forms property to create extensive drop-down lists for data capture.  After using the QField Project for a summer, I've made some changes to the attribute tables of the Geopackages (removed certain attribute tables, and added others) within that system to streamline the data collection workflow.

Now that I have a new Attribute Field layout and format established for these Geopackages, I am trying to append/translate the data that I collected this summer into the updated GeoPackage layers.

To start, I took my old CSV exports and modified all of the columns so that they have the same column layouts and formatting as the new GeoPackage Attribute Layers.  In theory, things should be able to directly translate and populate because they are in the same layout.

I am working from CSV Exports of the data and trying to populate my new Point-Data GeoPackage layer.  When I try to translate the data into the new Geopackage layer (I've tried direct copy-paste, exporting the CSV as a GeoPackage and copy-pasting, appending (Export>>save as>>append layer), there are brackets surrounding my data in all of the Attribute Fields that I have set as Drop Down lists (Value Map widget types in the Attributes Form property), meaning the data is not being registered as one of the drop-down options, even though the spelling, characters, etc. are all identical.  If I go into the drop-down, I can see that the bracketed data sits outside of the drop-down options.

Does anybody know how to translate data into GeoPackages with extensive Value Map Drop-downs so that the data fully populates and registers as one of these drop-downs?  Alternatively, if there is a way to translate this data efficiently?  It is unrealistic for me to manually change the bracketed data to the drop-down list as I have thousands of data points and tens of thousands of drop-down data fields that would need to be selected.

I've attached a sample of my QGIS Project and the data I am trying to append.

https://archer1981-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/kwillms_archercathro_com/EnwoYeupDKREufhELrGSgzgBTa9EEvNIrsKnUOyHdu9ypQ?e=33IqxZ